# Leaflet get all polylines added to map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Once you add one or more polylines to a map with clickable action and want to use measure tool *PolylineMeasure*, those polylines are in a way. How to get all created polylines in map to disable clickable like so you can do directly with polyline in a way you could click with marker on map

```
L.polyline(latlngs, {clickable: false}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Is **map** the **L.Map instance**? If not, what is your **L.Map instance**?

Comment: yes, it's L.Map

Comment: Cool,. then I hope that my answer solves your issue.

Comment: yes, thank you, just needed add few more events